# Why did the ajax call failed.The code below redirects to authenticate.php instead of echoeing text to login.html

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is the markup

```
<div class="header">
    Competitive Exams 
</div>

<div class="Content login">
    <form action="authenticate.php" method="get" id="login">    
        <ul>
            <li id="b9">Login</li>
            <li id="b10"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ></li>
            <li id="b12"><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"></li>
            <li id="b11"><input type="submit" value="MoveIn"></li> 
        </ul>
    </form> 
</div>
<div id="show"></div> 
<div class="foot">
    Copyright &copy 2013.All Rights Reserved.Created by :HACKSHAK & I-GOOGLEPLAY.  
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type= "text/javascript" src="debug.js"></script>
```

/*This is the javascript code for ajax call*/

```
window.onload = function(){
var form   = document.getElementById('login');
var output = document.getElementById('show'); 

form.onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var action = form.action;
    var method = form.method;
    var data   = {};
    var names =  document.querySelectorAll('#login [name]');

        for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
            var name   = names[i].name;
            var value  = names[i].value;
                data[name] = value;
        }

        var transmit = new Transmit(method,action,data,output).bind(transmit);

}

function Transmit(method,action,data,output){
    this.method = method;
    this.action = action;
    this.data   = data;
    this.output = output;

    var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    alert(xhr);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            this.output.innerHTML     = xhr.responseText;
            this.output.style.display = "inline-block";   
        }
    }

    xhr.open(this.method,this.action?this.data,true); 
    xhr.send();
}
```

}
when I run the code even after the default behaviour of the form is prevented it redirects to authenticate.php instead of making ajax call.

Comment: Doesn't the JS console complain about `xhr.open(this.method,this.action?this.data,true);` ?

Comment: No nothing shows up in console as a result of which i was unable to debug.But I was able to spot what was going wrong. I was constructing a query string (this.action?this.data) that was not sending data to php but was sending type of data to php.

Answer (score 2):

From the JS error console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,

You start a ternary operator here, but never finish it:

```
xhr.open(this.method,this.action?this.data,true);
```

Consequently, the function you assign to `onload` never gets properly parsed, so it never gets assigned, so you never assign your submit event.

It looks like you are trying to construct a query string, but getting it entirely wrong.

You need to loop over the object, `encodeURIComponent` all the keys and values, and then concatenate them (via `+`) using `=` and `&` characters before concatenating (again with `+`) to the action and the **string** `"?"`.

Authentication should generally be done with a POST request rather than a GET request though.

Comment: Hey @Quentin you were right.I was not appending correct content so I used for...in loop to loop through the data object.